# How to convert value greater than 1000 to char in java

Tags: java, encryption, char, integer, rsa

I'm developing my own `RSA` implementation in java. and while encrypting the data I'm encrypting each letter one by one and after calculating m^e mod n I'm getting values greater than 1000 and if i try to convert that value with `(char) 1034` I'm getting `?` this symbol for each character and I'm not able to decrypt the cipher text back to plain text what can i do please suggest some idea ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast to `char`. You need to encode your value. One possible simple encoding is hexadecimal. Radix-64 (or [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#OpenPGP)) are frequently used (as in OpenPGP). Another possible choice is [base85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85).

Comment: i think this can solve my problem but i am not able to find any example that can encode int values to base64 .. ??
can you provide me some example in java ??

Comment: @BinodPariyar You might use [`Base64`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64.html) from Bouncy Castle to be compatible with OpenPGP. If you don't need to be compatible with other PGP's you might try [`Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from apache commons (codec).

Comment: You might have to convert it to `byte[]` and then to base 64.